# react-native-vision-camera error when trying to startRecording "capture/unknown" while trying to start a video recording

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

Fairly new to react-native cli development, I have been trying to make a component record a video. I have an android device set up for testing the recording function, but whenever I try to start the recording, I get the following error:
`"code": "capture/unknown", "message": "An unknown error occurred while trying to start a video recording! prepare failed:-22", "userInfo": null`

I do make sure that the permissions are granted by the user, and that it's the proper device (the camera is on, and you can see a preview of what can be recorded)

What might be the reason behind this error?
I tried checking for permission, the dependecies are correct, and the camera is correctly initialize.

My current code

```
const cameraRef = useRef<Camera>(null);

  const [videoPath, setVideoPath] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices[0];

  const checkPermission = async () => {
    const newCameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
    const newMicrophonePermission = await Camera.requestMicrophonePermission();
    if (newCameraPermission == null) {
      ToastAndroid.show('Camera is not ready', ToastAndroid.LONG);
    }
    if (newMicrophonePermission == null) {
      ToastAndroid.show('Microphone is not ready', ToastAndroid.LONG);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkPermission();
  }, []);
  if (device == null) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }
  const startRecording = async () => {
    if(cameraRef.current){
      try {
        setRecordingStatus(true);
        await cameraRef.current?.startRecording({
          flash: 'off',
          onRecordingFinished: video => {
            setVideoPath(video.path);
          },
          onRecordingError: error => console.error(error),
        });
      } catch (e) {
        
        console.log('error on recording video: ', e);
      }
    }
  };
  const stopRecording = async () => {
    setRecordingStatus(false);
    await cameraRef.current?.stopRecording();
  };
```

what I return

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
              ref={cameraRef}
              style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
              device={device}
              isActive={true}
              video={true}
          /> 
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          {recordingStatus ? (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.recordingButton} onPress={stopRecording} />
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={startRecording} />
          )}
          
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of device=devices[0], try using device=devices.back;